# Galois group of splitting field of $X^4-6X^2+7$ is non-abelian

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions

> Let $E$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^{4}-6x^{2}+7$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. Show that $\operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbf{Q})$ is a non-abelian $2$-group.

Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: any group of order $4$ is Abelian

Comment: non abelian 2_group

Comment: @J.W.Tanner But what makes you think the Galois group of this polynomial has order $4$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman But it is 4, right? By the tower law, we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, i) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{7}, i): \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{7})] [\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{7}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2 \cdot 2 = 4$. The order of the Galois group is equal to the degree of the extension.

Comment: @LukePoeppel that is true, but $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{7},i)$ is not the splitting field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f$ is irreducible since $f(X+1)$ is Eisenstein for $p=2$. The roots of $f$ are $\alpha_1=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}$, $\alpha_2=\sqrt{3-\sqrt{2}}$, $\alpha_3=-\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_4=-\alpha_2$.

The splitting field of $f$ is $\Omega=\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$. Since $f$ is irreducible, $\alpha_1$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. Note that $\alpha_1 \alpha_2=\sqrt{7}\not\in \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1)\neq \mathbf{Q}(\alpha_2)$. But $\alpha_2$ is a zero of $X^2+\alpha_1^2-6\in \mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1)[X]$. This implies that $\Omega$ has degree $2^3$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. The Galois group is thus of order $2^3$. It remains to show that it is non-abelian..

**Hint.** If the Galois group were abelian, by the Galois correspondence every intermediate extension would be normal extension over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you..but can you explain more for me *$\alpha_1 \alpha_2=\sqrt{7}\not\in \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1)\neq \mathbf{Q}(\alpha_2)$*

Comment: This is the following lemma in Galois theory on quadratic extensions. Let $K$ be an extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ and $K(\alpha),K(\beta)$ be two quadratic extensions of $K$. Then $K(\alpha)=K(\beta) \iff \alpha\beta\in K$. In this particular case we let $K=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. The fields $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_2)$ are clearly quadratic over $K$ and so they are equal if and only if $\alpha_1\alpha_2=\sqrt{7}\in K$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you also see that the answer to the hint is already included in the answer..? :-)

Comment: "Since $f$ is irreducible, $\alpha_1$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbf{Q}$"..in this part I think

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1)/\mathbf{Q}$ is clearly not normal, since it does not contain its conjugate $\alpha_2$ by the argument above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107504/discussion-between-math1-and-rae306).

Comment: @rae306 I don't think I understand the lemma from your comment.  Does quadratic mean something other than "degree 2"?  What about ]$K = \mathbb{Q}$, $\alpha = i$, and $\beta = 1+i$?  Then $K(\alpha) = K(\beta)$ but $\alpha\beta \not\in K$.  Is there a fix which still solves the original question?

Comment: @CJD I see I forgot to add the condition $\alpha^2,\beta^2\in K$.